Encoding broken when switching to fish shell in Ubuntu WSL
When switching from bash to fish in Ubuntu WSL, the character encoding becomes broken in vim (and other terminal apps). In fish itself, everything looks fine:

But when I open vim from bash (first screenshot) or fish (second screenshot), there is a difference:


This is the output of the locale command in bash and fish:
jan@HSD-PF540YBG:~$ locale
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
jan@HSD-PF540YBG:~$ fish
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type help for instructions on how to use fish
~ > locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8


How does it break? Please EDIT your post to add further information explaining the situation more clearly and completely.

Sorry, my initial post was very unclear. I now added screenshots to illustrate.

Something in your fishrc is setting LC_ALL to en_US.UTF-8 – a generally valid locale, but one that's not installed on your system (as the "Cannot set" messages indicate).
You can either generate the locale using locale-gen (after enabling it via /etc/locale.gen first), or search your fish configuration for LC_ALL and remove that setting to have fish use the C.UTF-8 locale.
(Both C.UTF-8 and en_US.UTF-8 use the same encoding, but they differ in things like sorting order – AZaz vs AaZz – or date formats, etc.)
As a general note, LC_ALL should not be set permanently at all; that's the job of LANG. (That is, LANG is the baseline locale, other LC_xxx variables set locale for individual features, while LC_ALL is supposed to be only a temporary "override all" setting.) Because of that, it's not likely to be a system-wide setting; more likely to be your custom fishrc parameter.
